# testing php website on wampserver using android web browser

Tags: php, android, browser, ip-address

I am trying to test a php website using the web browser in android device (Google Nexus S). The Android version is 4.0.3. I have installed WampServer on my machine (running Windows 7) and have copied my php code in the wamp/www directory. I am able to test the code by browsing to localhost from the web browser on my machine. To test from my android device I tried browsing to my machine's public IP address, but the browser just gets stuck and doesn't load the page.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the device connected to your Wi-fi or just over the cell network?

Comment: The device is connected to my wifi

Comment: If it's on the same network you don't need to enter your public ip, just your local ip. Maybe you have some ports blocked or something.

Comment: Does it work if you browse to the public IP from any other machine?

Comment: @BillX It does not work if I browse public IP from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are browsing to your PUBLIC IP you need to ensure your Windows 7 firewall is allowing traffic on that port. Browsing from your localhost most likely works because your firewall doesn't block local traffic. Browsing to your PUBLIC IP means you are going out to the internet, hitting your firewall (router/windows 7?), and then trying to get to your server. Do you have port forwarding setup on your router? Have you tried accessing your local LAN IP rather than your public IP?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

References :

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,13744

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,30970,30989

I changed Apache httpd.conf to listen at port 8080 instead of 80.

Also I added a new inbound rule in my windows firewall to allow port 8080 TCP connections.